# Error in mlr::makeRegrTask Assertion on 'fix' failed: Must be of type 'numeric', not 'factor'

Tags: r, error-handling, sample

i try to write under program in r:

```
ds$fix<-as.numeric(ds$fix)
similar <- sample_locally ( data =  ds ,
                            explained_instance =  nobs ,
                            explained_var  =  "fix" ,
                            size  = 500 )
similar <- add_predictions(data=ds,
                          to_explain=similar,
                          black_box_model=model)

class(ds$fix)
expl <- fit_explanation(live_object=similar,
                        white_box="regr.lm")
```

---

and the following error occurs, It is if the type of 'fix' is numerical:

```
expl <- fit_explanation(live_object=similar,
+                         white_box="regr.lm")
Error in mlr::makeRegrTask(id = "lime_task", data = as.data.frame(dataset),  : 
 Assertion on 'fix' failed: Must be of type 'numeric', not 'factor'.
```

Comment: It was solved :)

Answer (score 0):

We needed to convert numeric similar$data$fix